# Как сделать так, что бы при горизонтальном скролле элемента, у его потомков тянулся фон на всю ширину родителя

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет!
Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, столкнулся с тобой проблемой, вроде на первый взгляд не сложно все, но ни как не могу ее без костылей решить.
У меня есть таблица на бутстрапе у которой должна быть возможность добавлять новые ячейки в строку и есть количество ячеек по ширине больше чем ширина окна браузера должен появляться горизонтальный скролл.

Это реализовать не сложно, но вот в чем сложность, возможность горизонтального скролла `overflow-x: auto` нужно вешать на родителя таблицы, что бы скрошилась вся таблица, а у каждой строки таблицы есть фон и нижняя рамка (именно у строки а не ячейки), и когда появляется горизонтальный скролл этот фон я строки таблицы прорисовывается только как бы на основной ширине экрана, а если таблицу скролить то фон не тянется на всю ширину (вместе со скроллом) таблицы.
Да, можно фон и рамку прописывать каждой ячейки таблицы и тогда все норм, но это не устраивает.

Подскажите пожалуйста как поступить в такой ситуации.

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
}

body,
h1,
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table__row {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.table__row--head {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8A2387 0%, #E94057 50%, #F27121 100%);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00000096;
}

.table__col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.table__col-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}

.table__col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Проскрольте вправо →</h1>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__row table__row--head">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему не устраивает задать фон для каждой ячейки?

Comment: @soledar10 Если бы фон должен был быть однородным, думаю проблем не возникло бы, но если фон нужен картинкой или градиентом, тут уже сложности. У меня у клиента как раз такая проблема сейчас, и я даже не вспомню как ее решить, поэтому и нашел похожий вопрос и объявил конкурс. Подправил как раз вопрос добавив градиента.

Answer (score 8):

```
.table{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.table__col{
    flex: 1;
}
.table__col-2{
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
}

body,
h1,
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.table__row {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.table__row--head {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8A2387 0%, #E94057 50%, #F27121 100%);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00000096;
}

.table__col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.table__col-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.table__col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Проскрольте вправо →</h1>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__row table__row--head">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте сделать так:

```
.table__row {display:inline; white-space: nowrap;}
.table__col {display: inline-block;}
```

придется, конечно, повозиться, чтобы задать нужное и вычистить лишнее.

Comment: хорошое решение)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно сделать вот такой падинг-марджин хак, который продолжит фон, но проблема будёт в том, что нужно чётко знать сколько елементов добавлено в конкретную строку таблицы и через js записывать данные в какую-то переменную и высчитывать результат:

```
.table__row {
  --cell-width: 16.6666%;

  padding-right: calc(var(--count-added-elements) * var(--cell-width));
  margin-right: calc(-var(--count-added-elements) * var(--cell-width));
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
}

body,
h1,
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table__row {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: calc(2 * 16.6666%);
  margin-right: calc(-2 * 16.6666%);
}

.table__row--head {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8A2387 0%, #E94057 50%, #F27121 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00000096;
}

.table__col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.table__col-2 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}

.table__col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Проскрольте вправо →</h1>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table__row table__row--head">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Дата</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Кол-во</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Счет отправил</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Компания</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Подписал</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table__col table__col-2">
      <span class="table__text">Статус</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```